# autoinst file missing from map

Tags: font-encodings, font-map

I want to use Overpass with `pdflatex`, so I've tried `autoinst`, but it doesn't quite seem to have worked. Here's what I've done,

```
sudo autoinst /usr/share/fonts/opentype/overpass/overpass-*.otf --sanserif --noupdmap --target=/usr/share/texmf-dist/
```

Then I ran updmap

```
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map Overpass.map
```

And now I've tried a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Overpass}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Text here

\end{document}
```

Which seems to complain

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/Overpass/LY1Overpass-TLF.fd) [1{/usr/share/tex
mf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 Overpass-Regular-tlf-ly1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for Overpass-Regular-tlf-ly1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps Overpass-Regular-tlf-ly1--base is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file Overpass-Regular-tlf-ly1--base): Font Overpass-Re
gular-tlf-ly1--base at 600 not found
```

I've had a look around, but haven't been able to find anything that solved this. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: does it work if you add `\pdfmapfile{Overpass.map}` to the document?

Comment: Hmm. It does, However both /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fonts/map/dvips/Overpass/Overpass.map and
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/Overpass/Overpass.map exist, and I've run `updmap-sys`. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if your updmap-sys command actually changes `/usr/share/tex
mf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`. If not try without sudo.

Comment: Well, the output of the command is this: https://pastebin.com/UpfYB1ZF does that help?

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo updmap-sys`? Does this write the map-file?

Comment: That fixed things, thanks :)